# ion-checkbox inside ion-grid makes grid blank

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have the following HTML:

```html
<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let item of playlist.data | filterBy: filter; let i = index;">
  <ion-item class="playlist-modal-item">
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col col-4>
          <h2>{{ item.name }}</h2>
          <p>{{ item.artist }}</p>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col col-4>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col col-4>
          <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="playlist.data[i].selected"></ion-checkbox>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item-options side="right">
    <button ion-button>Play Next</button>
  </ion-item-options>
  <ion-item-options side="left">
    <button ion-button>Play Last</button>
  </ion-item-options>
</ion-item-sliding>
```

My problem is with the `<ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="playlist.data[i].selected"></ion-checkbox>` line. If I remove this line it works as expected without the checkboxes. When I add the checkbox line the list items get repeated for each item in the array but the content of each item comes out blank.

I also tried doing it like this: `<ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="item.selected"></ion-checkbox>` which also does the same thing.

No errors are showing in the console and I know the properties are all correct and populated. The `item.selected` property is defaulted to false already too.

Edit: To clarify, when I have the checkbox there the list items get repeated but the content of each item is completely empty, but only when the checkbox line is there.

The JSON looks something like this:

```html
playlist = {
    data: [
        {
            name: 'foo',
            artist: 'bar',
            selected: false
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Edit: The filterBy is not the issue, it does the same thing when I remove it.

Comment: Try to add `name` property to checkboxes that should be.

Comment: elaborate your issue

Comment: @Aravind edited

Comment: by `content of each item` what you mean

Comment: @Aravind The list items get repeated as expected, but they're coming out blank. If I inspect the page the `ion-item` tags are empty.

Comment: @chrispytoes update the json data to post

Comment: @chrispytoes seems like your `filterBy` is culprit, can you add `filterBy` Pipe code?

Comment: also add `filter` value which is passed to pipe

Comment: @Aravind edited

Comment: @PankajParkar The filter works when the checkbox isn't there, and it still does the same thing when I remove it.

Comment: @chrispytoes then it would be great if you can provide a plunker with your issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As per said here in the **[ionicframework forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/bug-ion-checkbox-makes-entire-grid-disappear/81770)**

> Unexpected things inside `<ion-item>` need to be properly tagged. Add an `item-content` attribute to each of your `<ion-grid>` elements

So there is really a simple solution to this problem, just add `item-content` to your `ion-grid` tag like suggested above:

```
<ion-grid item-content>
```

And then it works like a charm! **Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/gw7h5mW3OJbPxw6xC3vb?p=preview

Comment: Thank you!!! I knew I wasn't crazy, the documentation should make this more visible.

Comment: I didn't use ion-grid element. But adding item-content attribute the wrapper fixed my issue. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use the iterator

```
<ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="item.selected"></ion-checkbox>
```

Update: There might be a typesafe error, use `?` in the bindings

```
<h2>{{ item?.name }}</h2>
<p>{{ item?.artist }}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so what I've found out is that when I move the checkbox outside the `ion-grid` the checkbox shows but nothing else. It seems like the issue lies with the ionic checkbox directive.

If I use a plain html checkbox it works fine, so I'm just going to do that and style it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to wrap my text in ion-label tags and my text magically appeared. :)

Example:

```
<ion-label><h2>Some text</h2></ion-label>
```